# Can I remove the USB/DVD during the "Installing Features" phase of Windows 10 Installation

Tags: installation, windows-10

Can I unplug the DVD/UBS during the "Installing Feature" phase of Windows 10 installation?

I'm installing windows on a tablet that has just one usb port and I'm afraid that it will lose charge if I don't unplug the usb hub which has the keyboard, mice and the usb.
[image]

Comment: No you can't. Atleast I have tried it once and Windows can't boot, forgot the error message.

Comment: Next time it restarts do a hard shutdown before it powers up again, then charge it, then plug the install usb back in and start up, it should resume.